# Why this alpine.js x-for looping 2 times

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I use the alpine.js to render a modal with a x-for loop who populate a select. Strange behavior, the x-for seems looping 2 times and  I can't understand why:

the code:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
        Alpine.data('load', () => ({
            indicateurs: [],
            indicateurDictionnaireForm: {},
            typeIndicateurs: {},
            detectedTypeIndicateur: '',
            loadIndicateur() {
                $('#overlay').fadeIn();
                fetch('<%= request.getContextPath() %>/mesures.load.action')
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => {
                        this.indicateurs = data;
                        $('#overlay').fadeOut();
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                    });
            },
            deleteIndicateur(id) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "DELETE",
                    url: "<%= request.getContextPath() %>/mesures.delete.action?indicateurDictionnaireId=" + id,
                }).then(() => this.loadIndicateur());
            },
            postForm() {
                return {
                    submitData() {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "<%= request.getContextPath() %>/mesures.save.action",
                            data: JSON.stringify(this.indicateurDictionnaireForm),
                            dataType: "JSON",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        }).then(() => {
                            this.loadIndicateur();
                            this.resetForm();
                            $('#modalIndicateur').modal('hide');
                        })
                    },
                }
            },
            editIndicateur(id) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "<%= request.getContextPath() %>/mesures.load.type-indicateur.action"
                }).then(data => {
                    this.typeIndicateurs = data;
                }).then(
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "<%= request.getContextPath() %>/mesures.edit.action?indicateurDictionnaireId=" + id,
                    }).then(data => {
                        this.indicateurDictionnaireForm = data;
                        this.detectedTypeIndicateur = data.typeIndicateur.code;
                        this.loadIndicateur();
                        $('#modalIndicateur').modal('show');
                    })
                );
            },
            resetForm() {
                this.indicateurDictionnaireForm = {};
            }
        }))
    })
</script>
```

the modal code:

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modalIndicateur">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title"><s:text name="indicateur.ce.add"/></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/save.action"
                      method="POST"
                      class="w-64 mx-auto" x-data="postForm()" @submit.prevent="submitData">
                    <div class="form-group" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-bottom: 5px">
                        <div class="row">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-2" style="text-align: left"
                                   for="libelle_fr">
                                <s:text name="indicateur.ce.libelle_fr"/></label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input id="libelle_fr" type="text"
                                       name="indicateurDictionnaireForm.libelleFr"
                                       class="form-control input-sm"
                                       x-model="indicateurDictionnaireForm.libelleFr">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-2" style="text-align: left"
                                   for="libelle_nl">
                                <s:text
                                        name="indicateur.ce.libelle_nl"/></label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input id="libelle_nl" type="text"
                                       name="indicateurDictionnaireForm.libelleNl"
                                       class="form-control input-sm"
                                       x-model="indicateurDictionnaireForm.libelleNl">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-2" style="text-align: left"
                                   for="code">
                                <s:text name="indicateur.ce.code"/></label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input id="code" type="text"
                                       name="indicateurDictionnaireForm.typeIndicateurCode"
                                       class="form-control input-sm"
                                       x-model="indicateurDictionnaireForm.code">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-2" style="text-align: left"
                                   for="code">
                                <s:text name="indicateur.ce.code"/></label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="flex flex-col w-full md:w-2/3">
                                    <select x-model="indicateurDictionnaireForm.typeIndicateurCode"
                                            class="form-control input-sm">
                                        <template x-for="option in typeIndicateurs" x-effect="console.log(detectedTypeIndicateur)">
                                            <option :key="option.code"
                                                    :value="option.code"
                                                    selected="option.code === detectedTypeIndicateur"
                                                    x-effect="console.log('code:', option.code, ' type: ', detectedTypeIndicateur)"
                                                    x-text="option.libellefr"></option>
                                        </template>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"
                                @click="resetForm()">
                            <s:text name="common.button.quitter"/>
                        </button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <s:text name="common.button.save"/>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the x-effect tag, I tried to log the value of the the detected item to be selected in the select tag and the value itself.

this is the console output when the modal is open:

```
// first loop

<empty string>

code: RESULTAT type: <empty string>
code: INCIDENCE type: <empty string>

code: REALISATION type: <empty string>

// second loop    

REALISATION

code: RESULTAT type: REALISATION

code: INCIDENCE type: REALISATION

code: REALISATION type: REALISATION
```

In the first loop I see the value from my function editIndicateur() is empty so I assume, alpine.s tries to render the modal before the call back and then do a second loop.

Have you an idea why the modal is populate before the value is return by the function and also why it loops a second time?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You bind the `select` element to the `indicateurDictionnaireForm.typeIndicateurCode` variable and its options to the `typeIndicateurs` variable (via loopig over it).

So when you call the `editIndicateur` method:

1. First you load only the select options via AJAX call and pass it to Alpine.js by `this.typeIndicateurs = data`.
2. Alpine detects that you changed `typeIndicateurs` and renders the template. This is the first loop. However neither `indicateurDictionnaireForm` or `detectedTypeIndicateur` have been set at this point, therefore these will be empty.
3. After that you make a new AJAX call, where you load additional form data and set `indicateurDictionnaireForm` and `detectedTypeIndicateur` variables.
4. Alpine.js detects that you changed two additional variables and renders the template again. This is the second loop.

This is normal behavior if you have two separate AJAX calls because the changes wont be in the same update queue. To fix this issue, you should create a local (non-reactive) variable inside `editIndicateur` function, then store the options's array in this variable at the first AJAX call. Then at the second AJAX call you set all 3 Alpine.js reactive variables together, therefore the changes will be in the same update queue, so Alpine.js renders the template only once.

```
editIndicateur(id) {
    let indicators;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "<%= request.getContextPath() %>/mesures.load.type-indicateur.action"
    }).then(data => {
        indicators = data;
    }).then(
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<%= request.getContextPath() %>/mesures.edit.action?indicateurDictionnaireId=" + id,
        }).then(data => {
            this.indicateurDictionnaireForm = data;
            this.detectedTypeIndicateur = data.typeIndicateur.code;
            this.typeIndicateurs = indicators;
            this.loadIndicateur();
            $('#modalIndicateur').modal('show');
        })
    );
},
```

Comment: Thanks Dauros, I have indeed a single loop with your solution. However, I still have one problem. The selected option is always the first option and not the one where the condition selected="option.code === detectedTypeIndicateur" is fit. I tried to log what happen and I don't understand why the option isn't set properly as it should: code: RESULTAT  type:  INCIDENCE selected:  false 
code: INCIDENCE  type:  INCIDENCE selected:  true 
code: REALISATION  type:  INCIDENCE selected:  false

Comment: Put a colon (shorthand for [`x-bind`](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/bind)) before the attribute, otherwise Alpine.js will ignore it: `:selected="option.code === detectedTypeIndicateur"`

Comment: thanks again. it seems to work but only when the modal is opened for the first time. When I close the modal and open again, it selects the first value.

Comment: Do you still see the correct value for `detectedTypeIndicateur` in the console?

Comment: Yes I do.
When I open the modal for first time:
detected:  REALISATION cdn.min.js 
code: RESULTAT  type:  REALISATION selected:  
code: INCIDENCE  type:  REALISATION selected:  
code: REALISATION  type:  REALISATION selected:  true 
When I close the modal and reopen it 
code: RESULTAT  type:  REALISATION selected:  
code: INCIDENCE  type:  REALISATION selected:  
code: REALISATION  type:  REALISATION selected:  true

Comment: I found the problem, it was a mapping problem on the backend. Thanks for your help Dauros